# Running an executable with flags from windows

Tags: windows

I have an exectutable file, lets say "program.exe"

if I run it from a command line I can give it some optional flags and the output will be according to these options. for example "program.exe -m"

Is it possible to run the program from windows by clicking it, and giving it a flag?

Comment: You can setup a shortcut to the program which can include the options, but every time you run that shortcut, the same options will be invoked.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either create a shortcut to the exe, or create a batch file, either way you can double click on it and it will run the exe with the parameters you specify.

Comment: Thanks, created a shortcut with the options I need.